# Connection to Terminal Server 2000 administrator console

Tags: remote-desktop, terminal-server, windows-terminal-services

One of my client have a Windows Server 2000 and I can connect to this server using remote desktop.

However, I can't connect to the Administrator Console.

I tried every switch available (I'm using windows 7) without success:

> %SystemRoot%\system32\mstsc.exe /v:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /admin
>
> %SystemRoot%\system32\mstsc.exe /v:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -admin
>
> %SystemRoot%\system32\mstsc.exe /v:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /console
>
> %SystemRoot%\system32\mstsc.exe /v:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -console

I did a lot of google search... some people mentionned there's a "trick" to connect to the administrator console but none of them has explained it.

Is this trick exist or is it an urban legend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The console option was added to Remote Desktop in Windows Server 2003. It is not available on Windows Server 2000.

Comment: And removed in 2008.